# How to get solace queue statistics from Solclient API? c#

Tags: solace

I am looking to retrieve some Solace queue stats e.g. the current messages spooled count out of the maximum limit for us to set a threshold to stop publishing more messages to the queue. 
Also, to subscribe to vpn events to track message discard rates.

By the time we receive errors e.g. MaxMsgUsageExceeded/SpoolOverQuota, it will be too late.

I can't seem to find any of these on SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging API
https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/net/html/7f10bcf6-19f4-beff-0768-ced843e35168.htm

Would be great if someone could help
(using C# for this)

Answer (score 1):

To poll for Solace queue stats from your C# application, you could use legacy SEMP over the message bus to make a SEMP request for the details that you want. Semp (Solace Element Management Protocol) is a request/reply protocol that uses an XML schema to identify all managed objects available in a message broker. Applications can use SEMP to manage and monitor a message broker.

To allow for legacy SEMP to be used over the message bus, as opposed to the management interface, it first needs to be enabled on the Solace PubSub+ message broker at the VPN level.

To publish a SEMP request with the Solace .Net Messaging API, perform the following steps:

1. Create a Session.
2. Create the message topic. “#SEMP//SHOW”

   ```
   ITopic topic = ContextFactory.Instance.CreateTopic( “#SEMP/<router name>/SHOW”);
   ```
3. Create a request message and set its Destination to the topic in Step 2:

   ```
   IMessage requestMsg = ContextFactory.Instance.CreateMessage();
   requestMsg.Destination = topic;
   ```
4. Set the SEMP request string as the binary attachment.

   ```
   string SOLTR_VERSION = "8_4_0" //change to the message-broker's version
   string SEMP_SHOW_QUEUE = "<rpc semp-version=\"soltr/" + SOLTR_VERSION +
     "<show><queue><name>queueName</name><detail></detail></queue></show></rpc>";
   requestMsg.BinaryAttachment = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SEMP_SHOW_QUEUE);
   ```
5. Call the SendRequest(…) method on Session.

   ```
   IMessage replyMsg;
   ReturnCode rc = session.SendRequest(requestMsg, out replyMsg, timeout);
   ```
6. The SEMP response is returned in replyMsg.
7. Obtain the binary attachment data from the reply message:

   ```
   replyMsg.BinaryAttachment
   ```

The binary attachment contains the SEMP reply for the command topic in the publish request.

---

The Solace PubSub+ message broker does raise an event when an egress message is discarded. However, it is only sent out approximately once every 60 seconds for the specified client so it is not possible to get these exact rates.

It is possible for your .NET application to subscribe to VPN-level events over the message-bus. To do this, you must first enable the Solace PubSub+ message broker to publish the events. You can then subscribe to the special topic and receive the events as messages.
The topic to subscribe to is:

```
#LOG/<level>/VPN/<routerName>/<eventName>/<vpnName>
```

The different levels can use the * wildcard. For example, if you wish to subscribe to all VPN events of all levels for the VPN apple on router QA-NY1, the topic string would be:

```
#LOG/*/VPN/QA-NY1/*/apple
```

Comment: So after we get binary response message should we turn it to string are we going to get xml message format , it is not clear, can you add more details

Answer (score 0):

SEMP (starting in v2) is a RESTful API for configuring, monitoring, and administering a Solace PubSub+ broker.

1-The swapper page link is [SEMP V2 API](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/swagger-ui/monitor/index.html)

2-The Swagger metadata definitions URL is located @ http://{solace-sever-url}/SEMP/v2/config/spec

3- From Visual studio, add REST API Client

[image: New Rest API Client]

4-In the configuration dialog pass swagger metadata URL (defined at step 2), for  code purpose I choose SolaceSemp as input value parameter for client namespace input.

[image: API REST Client Config Dialog]

4 Once you click ok, VS will create the client along with the models under SolaceSemp namespace

5 Start using the client as per following

```
using SolaceSemp;
using Microsoft.Rest;

var credentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials();
credentials.UserName = "place user name";
credentials.Password = "place password";
using (var client = new SolaceSempClient(credentials))
{
   var model = client.GetAboutApi();
}
```